PERN project Nginx config
I have a project running on Nginx with the website accessible through the domain https://petroleum.com.kz. However, static images located in the backend and served through port 8081 are not loading. The website itself and the API are working correctly.
My current Nginx configuration allows either the website to work without access to static files from the backend or access to those images, but then the website fails to load. How can I configure Nginx correctly so that both the website and static images from the backend are accessible through the domain?
my backend:
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const apiRoutes = require('./routes'); // Предполагается, что у вас есть маршруты

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8081;

// Middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Serve static files from the resources/static folder
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'resources/static')));

app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

My nginx config:
    server {
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name petroleum.com.kz www.petroleum.com.kz;

    # Serving static images from the backend
    location /static/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/static/;  # Proxy for backend static files
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # Handling all other requests
    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;  # For SPA
    }

    # Proxy for API requests
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081; 
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; 
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate/fullchain.pem;  # Path to SSL certificates
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificate/privkey.pem;  # Path to SSL key
    include /path/to/nginx/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /path/to/nginx/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
    if ($host = www.petroleum.com.kz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    if ($host = petroleum.com.kz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name petroleum.com.kz www.petroleum.com.kz;
    return 404;
}

